# Null reference exception in CIL

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit

This is really my first foray into CIL, and there must be something I don't get. I am generating a class using Reflection.Emit in C#, but getting an exception trying to use an enumerator.

```
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(List<PropertyChangeRecord>).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, changeDict);
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, changeDictType.GetMethod("GetEnumerator"));
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, moveNext);
getChangesIL.MarkLabel(loopStart);
//Some loop stuff. I can comment this out and still get the exception
getChangesIL.MarkLabel(moveNext);
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, changeDictType.GetMethod("GetEnumerator").ReturnType.GetMethod("MoveNext"));
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, loopStart);
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
getChangesIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

The exception:

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
    System.Collections.Generic.Enumerator.MoveNext() +14
```

I can't really see what could be null besides the dictionary I'm reading from, but that is set in the constructor

```
ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Call, typeof(object).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, changeDictType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, changeDict);
ctorIL.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

I can do the same thing in the debugger using C# without a problem, so I don't believe the class is bad, but at this point I'm at a loss as to what I'm doing wrong. What is causing this null reference exception?

Comment: Could you post a [mcve]?

Comment: I agree with svick - your constructor as written would corrupt the stack by leaving too many values on it before ret and would never compile.